# My component 'Recipe Items' is being rendered in a single column, when the correct one for each row is 5 columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to render a component from an .json file, until then okay, to be able to read and pass the api values ​​to my component ('RecipeItem'). The problem lies in the part of rendering, because the correct one would be the components being in 5 columns instead of only one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnGmi.png)
updated codes below !!!

```
File RecipeItem.js

const RecipeList = ({ searchString }) => {
    return(
    <div>
        {console.log('to aqui')}
        <img className="card-img-top img-fluid" src={searchString.thumbnail} alt={searchString.title} />
        <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{searchString.title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
                <strong>Ingredients: </strong>{searchString.ingredients}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

const RecipeItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-3 mt-4">
            <div className="card">
                {props.list && props.list.map((searchString, index) =>
                    <RecipeList searchString={searchString} key={index} />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

File App.js

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchString: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ searchString : data.results })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            <RecipeItem list={this.state.searchString}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this working ?

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            {RecipesData.results.map(recipe => 
                  <RecipeItem
                    title={recipe.title}
                    ingredients={recipe.ingredients}
                    source={recipe.href}
                    thumbnail={recipe.thumbnail} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's perfect, but what I was doing wrong ?, I'm a beginner and I can not see my  mistake.

Comment: The way that you were doing it renders: a new rowdiv, a new navbar... for each Recipe ! Because you re doing it inside the map fonction.

You should have a look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Please help me, I had to make some changes to the code to use state, however the code returned after these changes.